# Does (or will) the JRE include a CLI parser

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I normally use known CLI parsers (external libraries):

Apache Commons CLI http://commons.apache.org/cli/ (version 1.2)

Java Gems http://code.google.com/p/javagems/

JArgs http://jargs.sourceforge.net/

...

I haven't found one in the standard Java library, and I wonder if new versions of Java are providing an implementation so I can save a dependency. Does anyone know if there is something like that or a plan to include it in the future?

Answer (score 2):

If when you say "native" you mean "java implementation included into JDK", the answer is "no". Obviously you can always create your own (more or less simple) parser based on arrays and string operations provided by java and JDK.

Concerning to choice among java CLI parsers I'd suggest you to use [arg4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) and can refer you to the following discussion: [Java library for parsing command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters)

One of the answers contains a very long list of libraries.

And the last note. I do not know why do you want to "save the dependencies". Use one of build tools that manage your dependencies (e.g. ivy, maven, gradle) and forget about such problems. if you want to distribute your program as a single jar, you can pack all your dependencies together with your application. Both maven and gradle can do this. If you want to achieve minimal jar size ... make your choice: what is more important for you - size or modularity. In most cases size is not an issue these days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything included in the JDK. Actually OpenJDK itself uses [JOpt Simple](http://pholser.github.io/jopt-simple/) (see comment at the bottom of the page).